# Ansible Playbook msg var interpolation seems to only work with carrot > in yml file

Tags: ansible, yaml

Found an odd behavior I can't explain;

Running a small Ansible Playbook to just gather and display operating system information from hosts(For example: "Debian GNU/Linux 10")

I randomly stumbled across this solution(using carrot >), but can't find an explanation why it works this way;

```
---
  - name: Show Operating System version information
    hosts: all
    gather_subset: distribution_version
    tasks:

      - name: Display operating system facts
        debug: 
          msg: >
            {{ ansible_facts.lsb.description }}
```

Generates successful output;

```
ok: [orville.lan] => {
    "msg": "Ubuntu 19.10"
}
```

But if changed to this (remove >);

```
---
  - name: Show Operating System version information
    hosts: all
    gather_subset: distribution_version
    tasks:

      - name: Display operating system facts
        debug:
          msg: {{ ansible_facts.lsb.description }}
```

Then running the playbook generates this error sequence;

```
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: No JSON object could be decoded

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found unacceptable key (unhashable type: 'AnsibleMapping')

The error appears to be in '/home/eschin/Repositories/ansible-files/OperatingSystemReport.yml': line 9, column 17, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

        debug:
          msg: {{ ansible_facts.lsb.description }}
                ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:
                                                                                                                                      with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

I understand that the carrot > treats all following indented lines as a single line, i.e, converts newlines to spaces, but what other "secret sauce" is going on that makes the former work, but not the latter?

SOLUTION:

Simply making the interpolation a string, which the carrot `>` does for you, makes the second example work. I thought I'd tried this, and was sure it didn't work... but tried it again, and it works now. Coding Imps must have been messing with me 0:)

So this works;

```
---
  - name: Show Operating System version information
    hosts: all
    gather_subset: distribution_version
    tasks:

      - name: Display operating system facts
        debug:
          msg: "{{ ansible_facts.lsb.description }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{}}` is used for jinja2 template and to make that work, you need to put the template in a string within quote `' or "`. So below should work:

```yaml
msg: "{{ ansible_facts.lsb.description }}"

# Or, within a string without quote like below (better to use quote because the yaml processor implementation may differ for some special characters),

msg: The description is {{ ansible_facts.lsb.description }}
```

Now for,

> I randomly stumbled across this solution(using carrot >), but can't
> find an explanation why it works

`>` and `|` represents `folded` and `literal` [multiline strings](https://yaml-multiline.info) in yaml respectively. Since `>` already put the template within a string, it was working as you indicated on your question.

Have a look at basic [YAML syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html) too.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense... That's maddening... I'm certain I tried putting it in quotes(making it a string), and that still failed... but I just tried it, and it worked :)

Must have made a "tired mistake" I didn't notice.  Thanks!